# Array cells lose balance with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, overleaf

I am trying to make an array with latex.

my `code`:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={minimum size=10mm},
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
      border/.style={draw}
    
      \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes,
          row 2/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=0.4cm}},
          nodes={draw}]
      {
          $a_i$ & $4$ & $7$ & \textit{italic} & \textbf{bold text} & $a[0]$ \\
          \small{i} & \small{0} & \small{1} & \small{2} & \small{3} & \small{4} \\
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my caption}
\label{fig:array}
\end{figure}
```

but the border of the array loses its balance something like:

[image]

Please suggest how can I **fix this**? Or any other **smart way to draw this** type of figure?

Comment: Perhaps `nodes={draw,minimum height=??}` or even `nodes={draw,font=\strut}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `text height` and `text depth`, and `|[fill=the-color-you-like]|` in the cell you need to color:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={minimum size=10mm, text height=1.6ex, text depth=.4ex},
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
      border/.style={draw}
    
      \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes,
          row 2/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=0.4cm}},
          nodes={draw}]
      {
          $a_i$ & $4$ & $7$ & |[fill=lightgray, font=\itshape]|italic & \textbf{bold text} & $a[0]$ \\
          \small{i} & \small{0} & \small{1} & \small{2} & \small{3} & \small{4} \\
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my caption}
\label{fig:array}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel a need for another thing.... How can I fill the cell `italic` with background-color gray?

Comment: @KanchonGharami See my edit, and thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since it is actually a table, there is an alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[c,10mm]Q[c,10mm]Q[c,10mm]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c,10mm]},
  colsep = 2pt, rowsep = 2pt,
  rows={10mm}, row{2}={font=\small},
  hline{1,2}, vlines = {1}{},
}   
  $a_i$ & $4$ & $7$ & \textit{italic} & \textbf{bold text} & $a[0]$ \\
  i     & 0   & 1   & 2               & 3                  & 4      \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{my caption}
\label{fig:array}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]